# Modificar y Guardar con PHP archivos de texto

Tags: php, html

Tengo algunos problemas para poder guardar y abrir archivos de texto con PHP, Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']){ 
$open = fopen("frases/frase_del_dia.txt","w+"); 
$text = $_POST['update']; 
fwrite($open, $text); 
fclose($open); 
echo "<p>El Contenido se Actualizo!</p>";  
$file = file("frases/frase_del_dia.txt");
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text."<br />";  
} 
}else{ 
$file = file("frases/frase_del_dia.txt"); 
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ."' method='post'>"; 
echo "<br><textarea name='update' style='height:250px'>"; 
foreach($file as $text) { 
echo $text; 
}  
echo "</textarea><br>"; 
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Update' />\n 
</form>"; 
} 
?>
```

Como resultado me da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: submit in
>   /var/www/html/relaxedmind/editor.php on line 2

y no me aparece lo que tiene el archivo `frase_del_dia.txt` en `<textarea></textarea>`.

El contenido de mi archivo frase_del_dia.txt es el siguiente (una frase por cada linea):

```
Solo hay una felicidad en la vida – amar y ser amado
Cuanto más hacemos, más podemos hacer
Cáete siete veces y levántate ocho
El fracaso es éxito si aprendemos de el
Todo tiene belleza, pero no todo el mundo puede verla
El hombre necesita dificultades porque son necesarias para disfrutar el éxito
Es impresionante. La vida cambia muy rápido, de un modo positivo, si la dejas
Tienes que pensar de todas formas. ¿Por qué no pensar en grande?
Rodeate de gente positiva y serás una persona positiva
Cuando tienes un sueño tienes que agarrarlo y nunca dejarlo ir
```

Agradecería si me pueden dar una mano, Gracias!

Comment: el error que te está dando es porque la variable 'submit' no existe en el array $_POST. 

Fijate si estás enviando los datos por POST correctamente.

Comment: Agrega el código donde haces el submit

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Este es todo el código que uso, he puesto todo.

Comment: me podrías ampliar mas sobre como checar si se está enviando correctamente usando POST? recalcar que es todo el código que uso para hacer esto. @federhico

Comment: Ahí te elaboro una respuesta

Comment: Acabo de entender tu código. El error está al leer la variable $_POST['submit'] , deberías preguntar si está seteada con isset, y creo que no te daría error,  de igual manera es rara la forma en la que estructuras tu código

Comment: Vuelvo a no entender... El archivo ya está en tu pc y necesitas editarlo ? Explicate mejor

Comment: cuando lo pruebo me sale el mismo error que a ti, sin embargo me hace el update correctamente y se me carga bien el contenito en el textarea tambien

Comment: Uso este script para que cuando entren a la pagina los reciba un mensaje con una frase de motivación, Pero para que no tenga que bajar el archivo a mi PC y pueda agregar mas fácilmente nuevas frases decidí usar este script. Por ahora solo tengo el error de: `Notice: Undefined index: submit in /var/www/html/relaxedmind/editor.php on line 2` @federhico

Comment: Entonces el error de `Notice: Undefined index: submit in /var/www/html/relaxedmind/editor.php on line 2` no afectara en nada la ejecución del script? Si es así, habrá alguna manera de esconder ese error? @AdrianaHernández

Comment: Esto no es exactamente un error, es un "notice". Avisa que algo no funcionó bien del todo, pero no se produjo un error. En el php.ini se puede configurar para que se muestren o no los "notice"

Comment: @AdrianaHernández en mi archivo php.ini tengo así: `display_errors = off` he probado a usar `error_reporting(0);` y ahora ya no aparece, fue buena idea usarlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin modificar la visualización de errores (es útil tenerlos habilitados para depurar) puedes evitar ese mensaje de error cambiando la línea `if($_POST['submit']){` por:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Las explicación es que `if (VARIABLE) ...` **evalúa el valor de la variable**;  pero como no has enviado aún el formulario, entonces la variable *$_POST['submit']* no existe, y su evaluación dispara un error deteniendo el script.

Por otro lado, `if (isset(VARIABLE)) ...` **revisa si la variable existe**. Como no existe (no has enviado el formulario) el script continúa con la sección **else** de tu script.

Comment: Gracias! Esto me ha servido bastante, usando `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` ha resuelto el error que tenia, Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Esto no es exactamente un error, es un "notice". Avisa que algo no funcionó bien del todo, pero no se produjo un error. Pasa porque haces una llamada a un índice de un array o a una variable (en este caso `submit`) la cual no ha sido inicializada.
La desactivación de los `errores`, `warning`, `notice` y `deprecated` de PHP, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

Abre el archivo `php.ini` que se encuentra en tu servidor web.

En la directiva `error_reporting` puedes indicar que tipos de mensajes quieres que aparezcan, y cuales no.

Por ejemplo:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Así estás indicando que se muestren todos los errores excepto los `notice` y los `deprecated`. Por tanto en tu caso lo único que tienes que agregarle a esta línea es: `& ~E_NOTICE`
Reinicias el servidor y listo.
Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Gracias! esto me ha salvado la vida, Un cordial saludo y gracias por tomarse el tiempo para ayudarme!.

Answer (score 1):

He aquí una mejora a tu código. Pruébalo y me dices

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST['submit'] && isset($_POST['update'])){ 
$text = $_POST['update']; 

$open = fopen("frases/frase_del_dia.txt","w+"); //abres el fichero en modo lectura/escritura
fwrite($open, $text);//escribes el contenido en el fichero
echo "<p>El Contenido se Actualizo!</p>"; 

$text = fread($open, filesize($open)) //recuperas el contenido del fichero
echo $text;

fclose($open);//cierras el fichero
}
else{ 
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ."' method='post'>"; 
echo "<br><textarea name='update' style='height:250px'>"; 

$open = fopen("frases/frase_del_dia.txt","r"); //abres el fichero en modo lectura
$text = fread($open, filesize($open)) //recuperas el contenido del fichero
echo $text;
fclose($open);//cierras el fichero  

echo "</textarea><br>"; 
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Update' /></form>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Me salta el error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\relaxedmind\editor2.php on line 10`.

Comment: Ok, lo revisare entonces... Si Adriana Hernández te salvo la vida al menos marca la respuesta como correcta, no?

Comment: Gracias, la respuesta de @Adriana Hernández me ha salvado la vida en cuanto a los errores y como ocultarlos, pero alguien mas arriba me ayudo con una respuesta que directamente arregla mi problema con el código, Una disculpa si se malinterpreto mi comentario y/o causa alguna molestia.

Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Sustituye filesize($open) por filesize("frases/frase_del_dia.txt"). Debe corregir el error